# Encoding an image into base 64 encoded byte format

Tags: go, encoding, base64

When I am running same code on two different version of Go (go1.10.8 darwin/amd64 and go1.6.1 linux/amd64) in earlier version following code is encoding string fine but in later version it is encoding string in wrong format.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var (
        file     *os.File
        fileInfo os.FileInfo
        err      error
        content  []byte
    )
    filePath := "random.jpeg"
    if file, err = os.Open(filePath); err == nil {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
        bufWriter := bufio.NewWriter(&buf)
        if content, err = ioutil.ReadAll(reader); err == nil {
            _ = content
            encoder := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, bufWriter)
            encoder.Write(content)
            //  finalSlice, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(bufWriter)
            //  fmt.Println("and the final slcie becomes", finalSlice)

            encodedString := string(buf.Bytes())
            fmt.Println("and the final bytes becomes", encodedString)
            _ = fileInfo
            _ = encoder
        } else {
            fmt.Println("error cma in", err)
        }
        //} //else {
        //fmt.Println("And here errror becimes", err)
        //}
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("here the error become")
    }
}
```

what could be the possible reason

Answer (score 2):

You have to flush the buffered writer, else there may be data left in its buffer. Whether it has may depend on version:

```
encoder := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, bufWriter)
encoder.Write(content)
encoder.Flush()
```

Although since you're already writing to an in-memory buffer, the buffered writer is completely unnecessary, write directly into `buf`.

```
encoder := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, &buf)
encoder.Write(content)
// No flush needed.
```

Also, recommended to [update your Go SDK](https://golang.org/dl/), latest version is 1.14, Go 1.6 and Go 1.10 are not supported anymore.

Comment: @as.beaulieu Those bugs are in the IDEs, and not in the Go SDK.